# Google Maps with kml layer. Google adds _blank to info window links

Tags: google-maps, kml, infowindow

First time asking question here. All new to coding so be gentle.

I have this Google Map, where I'm inserting ~70 markers via a kml file which includes some info for the map info windows. Thats all working very fine.

But, when I add links to the info windows Google somehow adds 'target="_blank"' to those links making them open in a new window. However I want the links to open in the same window. Is there a way to do this?

The code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.100, 10.000), zoom: 8};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: 'link-to-my.kml'});
ctaLayer.setMap(map); }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And the info I have in the kml file looks like this:

```
<Placemark>
<styleUrl>#icon-981</styleUrl>
<name>Some name</name>
<description><![CDATA[<a href="link.html">Click this</a>]]></description>
<Point>
<coordinates>8.450037000000066,55.477908,0.0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
```

So, basicly the question is: How can I get those links to open in the same window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<description/>` will be sanitized to prevent abuse(Note that a KMLLayer may also be used by other ressources, e.g. it may be loaded in maps.google.com, so they must be sure that it doesn't include malicious code).

I guess the `target="_blank"` is a part of the cleansing, it should prevent from leaving the current page.

There may be different options to remove the `target`, the simpliest should be to manipulate the `infoWindowHtml` before the InfoWindow opens:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer,'click',function(e){
    e.featureData.infoWindowHtml 
     = e.featureData.infoWindowHtml.replace(/target="_blank"/g,'');
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it's not working. There is still the _blank on the links even after adding you bit of code.

I inserted it just before </script> - correct or should it go elsewhere?

Comment: You must place it somewhere where `google` and `ctaLayer` is accessible: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ryTr6/